# Deshabilitar botón en horario prestablecido

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos estoy tratando de deshabilitar un botón y que solo se muestre en ciertos horarios(8:00am - 12:00 pm y 14:00pm - 17:00pm) utilizando javascript
pero no logro conseguirlo solo se esconde pero no en el tiempo que mencione anteriormente para ello eh probado con la siguiente función

Este es el botón

```
<a href="https://wa.link/sm1s1j" class="btn-flotante"><img src="assets/img/iconos/wt.png" width="100" height="100" id="btnw"></a>
```

codigo javascript que eh probado

```
 window.setInterval(
    function(){
      var d = new Date();
      var hour = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()
      let hoursActive = ['08:00', '12:00', '14:40', '16:00']
      
      if(hoursActive.includes(hour)){
        document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'block';
      }else{
        document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
,2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así como estás definiendo los horarios activos `let hoursActive = ['08:00', '12:00', '14:40', '16:00']` es difícil identificar si la hora actual está dentro de esos rangos. Además, si la hora es 13:15 no va a coincidir con ninguno de los elementos y se va a ocultar el enlace, mostrando solo cuando haya una hora que coincida (08:00, 12:00, etc.).

Te sugiero crear un arreglo donde cada rango contenga dos elementos: inicio y fin.

De esta forma, usas un ciclo para realizar la comparación y es más sencillo.

**Edición:** El método `getHours()` devuelve un número entre cero y 23, por lo que hay que forzar a que de 0 a 9 tenga un cero al inicio. Con [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) se soluciona.

```js
function verifica() {
      let d = new Date();
      let hour = d.getHours().padStart(2, '0')+':'+d.getMinutes();
      // Establecer horarios activos con inicio y fin
      let hoursActive = [
          ['08:00', '12:00'],
          ['14:40', '16:00']
      ];
      // Saber si se está en horario activo o no, con una variable
      let isActive = false;
      // Recorrer horarios activos para saber si la hora actual se incluye en uno
      // Debe ser con for para poder detenerlo
      for(let i = 0; i < hoursActive.length; i++) {
          // El formato de 24 horas se puede comparar como cadena
          if(
              hour >= hoursActive[i][0] // Mayor o igual que el inicio
              && hour <= hoursActive[i][1] // Y menor o igual que el fin
          ) {
              // La hora actual está dentro de horario activo
              isActive = true;
              // Fin del ciclo, no es necesario seguir procesando
              break;
          }
      }
      // Verificar que está en horario activo
      if(isActive) {
          document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'none';
      }
}
// Crear intervalo
window.setInterval(verifica, 2000);
// Ejecutar al cargar página
verifica();
```

```html
<a href="https://wa.link/sm1s1j" class="btn-flotante"><img src="assets/img/iconos/wt.png" width="100" height="100" id="btnw"></a>
```

Para evitar que aparezca durante dos segundos en horarios que no debería, separa la función y ejecútala al cargar la página. El intervalo se encargará de mostrar u ocultar conforme pase el tiempo.

Comment: Al refrescar la pagina vuelve aparecer , sabes el ¿Porque?  la idea es que ya se muestre hasta mañana las 8:00 am

Comment: @Codej vuelve a aparecer por los primeros dos segundos porque la función `setInterval` no ejecuta el callback hasta pasado el tiempo que le declaras. Para que no aparezca, haz una llamada al callback antes de iniciar el setInterval.

Comment: @Codej, listo, edité la respuesta para solucionar eso.

Comment: @Codej, volví a editar para asegurar que la hora siempre tenga dos dígitos. Aplica para 00 a 09.

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una posible solución que tiene precisión de milisegundos. Para ello he creado una función `isActive` que recibe como parámetros un arreglo cuyos índices pares representan el inicio del intervalos y los índices impares el final. Por ejemplo si quieres los intervalos 1:00-2:00, 4:00-5:00 y 6:00-7:00 usa  `["1:00" , "2:00" , "4:00", "5:00", "6:00", "7:00"]`.

La función convierte las fechas en la hora relativa en milisegundos del día actual para poder hacer la comparación. Si la hora actual cae dentro de alguno de los intervalos, regresa `true` de lo contrario regresa `false`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar. En este snippet, si la hora actual entra dentro de los intervalos, el botón permanecerá, pero si no entra, desaparecerá:

```js
function isActivated(hoursActive) {
    const dates = hoursActive.map(dateString => {
        const [hour, minute] = dateString.split(':')
        let date = new Date()
        date.setHours(hour, minute, 0, 0)
        return date
    })

    let isActive = false;
    const now = new Date();

    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i = i + 2) {
        isActive = isActive || now.valueOf() >= dates[i].valueOf()
            && now.valueOf() <= dates[i + 1].valueOf()
    }
    return isActive
}

window.setInterval(
    function () {
        let hoursActive = ['08:00', '12:00', '14:40', '14:00']
        if (isActivated(hoursActive)) {
            document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('btnw').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    , 2000);
```

```html
<button id="btnw">Botón</button>
```

Comment: Tenia que quitar el 200 que se ve al final y ya funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias a todos